# How i can change text direction in Osclass script from ltr to rtl

Tags: right-to-left, web-development-server, osclass

I would like to move some elements in the publish form from right to left, already created and edited the rtl.css changing the all float from left to right, still some elements including the drop down menus didn't change as shown in the site:
here where script is installed http://sudan-ads.com

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: Here is code https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437865/10104884

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change header.php file in your theme in html tag

```
<html dir="rtl" lang="<?php echo str_replace('_', '-', osc_current_user_locale()); ?>">
```